# Got app approved and "pending contract", but no buttons appear in Bank, Tax information

Tags: accounts, app-store-connect

The app status says that the "App approved, but one or more of your contracts is not yet in effect". So I went to the bank, tax information module: in here is a Request Contracts list, which shows one line for "Paid Apps" and one for "iAds". Next to it, my name stands as Legal Entity. There is a button "Request" on each line - but when I click it, it only shows my personal home address data in a simple form (but no bank accounts, no tax information etc.). Nothing else to click, nothing else to check, nothing else to view. Nothing. And there are no "Set Up" buttons either like shown in their video tutorial. No other buttons. I can do nothing here.

Is this just Apple doing administrative tasks on their side and I should just wait? Maybe it's because I'm fairly new as I registered this month (3 weeks ago) as an Apple developer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is ridiculous, but I accidentally found the solution: when clicking the "Request" button in the Taxes/Contracts module a form popped up displaying my address data. No agreement, contract texts, however. 
Then I clicked "Save" to confirm this address data. Nothing happened, the form stayed. 
Then I clicked "Save" again. 
And again. 
And again. 
And again. 
After the 5th time of clicking "Save" in a row - suddenly the agreement and contract window appeared!!!

Apple, you must be kidding! Really! I can reproduce this weird mechanic anytime. For anyone stumbling onto the same problem - make sure you DON'T click on "Cancel", or you will never see the requested agreement.

Comment: It's July, 2015 and I had to do the same thing. Agreed.